# Django settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL defined in separate module

Tags: django, python-3.x

What is the proper way to say what is my **AUTH_USER_MODEL**?

I have the following set:

**Folder structure:**

--- backend 
----- api 
-------- models 
----------- user.py

**user.py** lies within **models** folder

**in settings.py:**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'api',
]
```

**The model:**

```
class User:

    class Meta:
        app_label = "myapp"
```

And when I run any manage.py command, for example

> python manage.py showmigrations

I get this error:

> LookupError: No installed app with label 'myapp'.

The problem solution would be renaming **api** folder to **myapp**, which I cannot do due to some restrictions on model names. 
 Or setting AUTH_USER_MODEL to **api.User**, but this will incur changing all data table names and those must remain the same

Data table names starting with '**myapp_**' should not change

Comment: I don't understand why you have put "myapp.User" rather than "api.User", if the model is in the api app.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have reasons: If I change to "api.User" then I will need to update all migrations and change hence all the table names, which is not desirable on production. The problem is in migrations

Comment: No, the problem is in your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting.

Comment: Also where is your `manage.py` or where is the root of your project? Is that `backend`?

Comment: @trixn yes, backend is the root and `manage.py` is located in `backend` folder

Comment: @Dmitry then try my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to change AppConfig.label in class MyAppConfig(AppConfig), so if you update your answer, I will accept it. Changing name ends in nothing, it must be the real name of the module the code sits in, but adding label = 'arbitrary_name' is actually the solution

Answer (score 3):

Given your folder structure looks like that:

```
backend
└── api
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── apps.py
|   └── models
|       ├── __init__.py
|       └── user.py
├── manage.py
└── settings.py
```

then you can [create an app config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) in `backend/api/` by creating a file called `apps.py` inside it. There you can rename your app:

**backend/api/apps.py**:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
    verbose_name = _('My App')
```

Also you need to add this to the `__init__.py` inside that folder:

**backend/api/__init__.py**:

```
default_app_config = 'api.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Also if you want to use `myapp.User` as your user model you also have to import in in the `models` module:

**backend/api/models/__init__.py**:

```
from .user import User
# or use "from .user import *" to import everything but then make sure you have __all__ defined in user.py
```

Comment: Yes, exactly the same folder structure

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp': 
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) -> 
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry) -> 
File "/Users/dmitri/Envs/chat3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 142, in create app_module = import_module(app_name)

Comment: The solution was to change AppConfig.label in class MyAppConfig(AppConfig), so if you update your answer, I will accept it. Changing name ends in nothing, it must be the real name of the module the code sits in, but adding label = 'arbitrary_name' is actually the solution

Comment: I have anoter question related to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` but wasn't that big of a question to open a new question for it. Why don't we say `myApp.models.CustomUser` and say `myApp.CustomUser` instead?